# Layering on base map in ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I am new to using spacial data in R.  I am trying to plot 2 layers on a base map but for some reason I can't get the syntax right.

```
qmplot((Longitude, Latitude, data = df1, colour = "blue",
zoom = 7) +
geom_point(
   aes(x = Longitude, y= Latitude),
   data = df2, colour = "red")
)
```

Comment: It would help if your example were [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include sample data (we have no idea what's in `df1`) and be specific about what goes wrong. Is there an error message (include it)? Do you not what what you expect (describe what you expect)?

Comment: The parens are messed up.  should be `qmplot(stuff) + geom_point(other stuff)`